# Поддержка '0000-00-00 00:00:00' значения поля DATETIME в mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, datagrip

Пример создания одного из столбцов таблицы:

```
`f_stamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Ранее, на **Ubuntu 14.04.4** [**mysql 5.6**], значение этого поля отображалось нормально, в данный момент, при установленной Ubuntu 16.06 и mysql 5.7 - отображается как null.

---

*Что сделал: убрал из глобальной переменно флаги: NO_ZERO_DATE, NP_ZERO_IN_DATE и STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.*

---

В итоге - просматривая данное поле на сервере через mysql-client - поле отображается так, как и хотелось бы ('0000-00-00 00:00:00'), однако, подключаясь **DataGrip**'ом с удаленной машины - вновь вижу null, хотя ранее все тот же DataGrip показывал нужное значение.

UPD: [для тех, кто закрыл вопрос] В Database Administrators на этот вопрос ответили. Ну это я так, к сведению.

UPD2: [для тех, кто закрыл вопрос, конечно же] - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3377

Comment: Попробуйте создать дамп базы данных и перенакатить его по-новой. Скорее всего какая-то ошибка миграции. На чистой инсталляции, новой таблице ситуация не воспроизводится.

Comment: Спасибо за совет ! Но после изменения вышеуказанных флагов все заработало, меня только беспокоит тот момент, что [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) отображает такие поля некорректно.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что помимо того, что я убрал несколько флагов - я еще один и добавил: **ALLOW_INVALID_DATES**. И еще маленький совет тем, кто ни разу не баловался с флагами - проинициализируйте переменную **sql_mode** в файле _mysql.cnf_, и не забудьте проверить, что в этом файле присутствует строка **[mysqld]**.

Comment: @cheops, если Вам интересна причина - посмсотрите, обновил пост.

Comment: Спасибо. Проголосовал за переоткрытие, если наберется достаточное количество голосов, поместите пожалуйста решение в ответ. Думаю будет многим интересно.

Comment: Всё верно, в 5.7 изменили дефолтный sql_mode. Пока что эти невалидные даты можно разрешить изменением sql_mode. Но для случая отсутствия даты лучше бы использовать NULL.

Comment: @Мелкий, я так и сделал - поправил флаги (если так можно выразиться) в sql_mode - и все заработало. Но вопрос то у меня касался DataGrip'a - он мне показывал не то, что я ожидал увидеть.

Comment: @cheops, спасибо за поддержку. Хорошо, сделаю )